# Search for a list of 7000 images names

Tags: file, search, windows-10

I have 192000 images and I want to search for list of 7000 images names. and copy only these images. Is there any way to do it by coding or any way?
note: I use windows 10

Comment: how are you storing the list of image names? In text file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question but if you open the folder where are your images with the folder explorer, and you search the name of the wanted image, you can cut and paste all the images you have with the good name in an other folder.

I don't know if it's the answer you want sorry... But I hope it will help you

Comment: I have (7000) names of images and I want to find only the (7000) images from folder which is containing 192000 images

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing the image file names in text file (one image file name per line) below vbs code can be useful

```
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sourceFolderPath = "C:\Selenium\images\"
targetFolderPath = "C:\Selenium\copied_images\"

Set oFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Selenium\images\names.txt")
arr = Split(oFile.ReadAll(), vbNewLine)

For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
    Filename = sourceFolderPath + arr(i)
    If (oFSO.FileExists(Filename)) Then
        oFSO.CopyFile Filename, targetFolderPath
    End If
Next

set oFile = Nothing
set oFSO = Nothing
```